# Get width of the previous list item and calculate current margin

Tags: php, jquery, list, width, margin

I'm using PHP to dropdown a main menu. My menu looks like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown_top">
  <li style="width:20px;">  /*main categories, width is an exapmle i don't realy know the exact width */
    <ul style="margin-left:-10px>
      <li></li>    //subcategories
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>  //main categories
    /* the code i'm looking for, must do something like this: */
    <?php
      $style = - widthOfThePreviusMainCategoryLi() + marginLeftOfThePrevius_Ul_Li_Ul() = -30px ;
    ?>
    <ul style="margin-left:<?=$style?>;"> /* this ul margin-left is the problem */
      <li ></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the width of the previous list item and calculate the current margin.

I saw an example with the jQuery function `outerWidth()`, but I can't figure out how I can use that in my case.

I tried this after the menu is published, but what am I doing wrong?

```
<pre><code>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var number = $("#topmenu li").size();
            var marginSum = -10;   //the first

            for(i=2;i &lt; number; i++)
            {
                marginSum = marginSum - $("#topmenu li").slice(0,(i-1)).outerWidth(true); //OR
                marginSum = marginSum - $("#topmenu li:eq("+(i-1)+")").outerWidth(true);

                alert("Μargin of "+i+": "+marginSum + " prev width:"+$("#topmenu li:eq("+(i-1)+")").outerWidth(true)+" Margin:"+marginSum);  //OR   
                alert("Μargin of "+i+": "+marginSum + " prev width:"+$("#topmenu li").slice(0,(i-1)).outerWidth(true)+" Margin:"+marginSum);    

                // $("#topmenu li").width(width);
            }
        }); 
    </script>
</code></pre>
```

I believe that the function `outerWidth(true);` also calculates the nested `ul`, but I don't know that for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. This is my code:

```
<script>
    function setMenuInPlace(){
        //fix ul category menu
        $('.dropdown_top .dir').css({'margin-left' : '0'});
        var totalLis_w = num =0;
        var dtopWidth = $('#topmenu .dropdown_top').width();

        //set nested ul in place
        var mLeft = $('.dropdown_top').offset().left;
        var myLeft = mLeft + 2; //Left per 2 pixels for leaving a small space
        // alert (mLeft);
        $('.dropdown_top li ul').offset({left : myLeft});

        //calculate free space for lis
        $('.dropdown_top .dir').each(function(){
            num ++;
            totalLis_w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
            // alert($(this).outerWidth(true));
        });
        var dtop_free = dtopWidth - totalLis_w;
        var mLeft_Li = (dtop_free/ num) -2 ; //leaving a small space 2 pixels.
        if(mLeft_Li > 0)
             $('.dropdown_top .dir').css({'margin-left' : mLeft_Li});
        // alert(\"lis width\"+totalLis_w+\" free space:\"+dtop_free+\" mLeft\"+mLeft_Li);
    }
    ( function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setMenuInPlace();
        });
        //$(window).load(function(){
        // setMenuInPlace();
        //});
        $(window).resize(function() {
            setMenuInPlace();
        });
    } ) ( jQuery );
</script>
```

Class "dir" are the main categories list items: `<li class="dir">`.

Answer (score 0):

That will need a lot of work on the server side because there's no way of knowing the width of an element unless you make a lot of calculation like calculate the number of characters the font size and weight maybe borders or margins and paddings, anyway <strike>the best way to do that in the client side with Javascript or like you said with jQuery</strike>.
It's better to do it wwith pure CSS, here's some videos tutorials on how to do that:

- [Creating a 100% CSS dropdown menu by Free Web Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL46837BE17F92FAD9).
- [Adam khory's video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PBa5juYwaA).
- [PHPAcademy's video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aA8eB6P2sM).

Hope this help.

Comment: Τemporary, i have solved this by using static array $style(-10, -30, ...), for the current menu. But the menu changes dynamically. How can 'i do that with jquery?

Comment: You don't need to code that really you could use [Twitter-bootstrap navbar with Dropdowns](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns), or just populate the nested list with PHP without the CSS and then use the CSS in a Stylesheet to style your elements by making the width of the lis fixed with known margins and padding you can add the right margin to the nested ul. I know I said you can do it but you don't really need too, it's easier to use pure CSS for it, chack my updated answer for more details.

Comment: Actually, i want my menu to look like this http://www.caremarket.gr/DefaultV2.aspx . But in my site i want to fix the margin problem of the nested ul. Also my menu will change dynamically, so to put fixed margins is just a temporary solution.